# Where are the controls for debugging Node code in VS Code?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Trying to use VS Code for debugging.

I've got most of the way but stuck on finding the controls as shown in VS Code help.  when I press F5 I get `Process exited with code 0` and I'm not sure what to do about that.

My screen:

[image]

The VScode help screen from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging:

[image]

How do I find these controls:

[image]

My `launch.json` file is:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into why the debugger process has exited 0? If that's not running, you're not going to see those controls. Give a [mre].

Comment: I had same problem. Debugging didn't work with node v8 ("Process exited with code 0"), but worked with latest version (v12 in my case). VSCode version is 1.47.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three parts:

1. Need to start node process in the terminal after adding:

   ```
     "start": "node index.js"
   ```

   to `package.json` in the `"scripts"` section
2. Now do `npm start` in the terminal
3. You will see the debugger controls appear and if you then switch to the 'debug console' mini-tab as shown below you can interact with the process in the debug console, e.g.

   [image]